# Can I use .htaccess to save the full REQUEST_URI in a variable?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a little problem with .htaccess: With this code,

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ^(.*)$ TEST=$1
```

TEST will give me `/index.php` even when my URL (which is rewritten) is something else.

For example:

```
// URL: http://www.example.com/us_en/module/controller/
echo $_SERVER['TEST']; // returns /index.php
echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; // returns /us_en/module/controller/
```

I would like TEST to have the full path in REQUEST_URI from .htaccess and not just `/index.php`.

I know this might be caused by something in the rewrite conditions so I’ll show you what I have:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Comment: Happy new year - you forgot to add your question :)

Comment: Sorry edited:
I would like to have the full path in Request_URI from .htaccess and not just `/index.php`

Comment: It's probably because after each pass of mod_rewrite processing your URI, the new URI is used to process `.htaccess` again. What do you want to use it for? Could you just process in PHP or use other alternative ways?

Comment: +Alvin Wong yes I'm doing it in PHP right now, but I wanted to avoid 1 redirection. But I think it's harder than expected...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try one of these:

```
SCRIPT_NAME=/sw/lib/w3s/tree/global/u/rse/.www/index.html
SCRIPT_FILENAME=/u/rse/.www/index.html
SCRIPT_URL=/u/rse/
SCRIPT_URI=http://en1.engelschall.com/u/rse/
```

These are [Environment Variables](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#EnvVar).

They also should be available in PHP’s `$_SERVER` superglobal.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but where do I put this ?

Comment: I did it in PHP, +1 for your help ;-)